# Loop to list names of files with NAs

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, na

I have a folder called "Holder" with a list of files in it. I am trying to write a loop that will iterate through the list of files, and add to a vector (called "FileList") the names of files that contain NAs. When I check my statement "sum(is.na(Orig))>=1" on a file that I know has an NA, it returns "TRUE". However, when I source the script, my vector returns "logical(0)". What am I missing here?

```
setwd("/Users/.../Desktop/NAs")
fileNames <- Sys.glob("*.csv")
fileNumbers <- seq(fileNames)
FileList<-vector()

for (fileNumber in fileNumbers) {
  Orig <- read.csv(fileNames[fileNumber],
                       header = TRUE,
                       sep = ",")
    
  if (sum(is.na(Orig))>=1) {
    append(fileNames[fileNumber], FileList)
  }}
```

Also tried the below, with same result:

```
  if (sum(is.na(Orig$D_postIAT))>=1) {
    append(fileNames[fileNumber], FileList)
  } else if (sum(is.na(Orig$D_preIAT))>=1) {
    append(fileNames[fileNumber], FileList)
  }
```

Comment: Orig is the name of the dataframe that you've read in.  That's why you're getting that logical(0) issue. You most likely want to specify the name of a column where you are looking for NA's.

Comment: @thehand0 thanks. I tried indexing a specific column, and added in my attempt at that above, but met with same outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues here.

1. You want `seq_along()`, not `seq()`. `seq()` expects numeric arguments.

```
fileNumbers <- seq_along(fileNames)
```

2. `vector()` defaults to creating a logical vector, but you want a character vector.

```
FileList<-vector(mode = “character”)
```

3. You need to assign the results of each `append()`. With very few exceptions (outside of R6 classes), objects in R aren’t modified in place.
4. Your arguments are backwards: `append()` takes the object to be
   appended to, then the object to append.
5. Finally, you can simplify
   your code by using `any()` instead of `sum() >= 1`, and by combining
   the two `if` clauses into one with an or. So try:

```
if (any(is.na(Orig$D_postIAT)) || any(is.na(Orig$D_preIAT))) {
    FileList <- append(FileList , fileNames[fileNumber])
  }
```